# SharePoint workflow Create Item of a custom content type uses old template

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a workflow in SharePoint 2013 that does a "Create Item" task on a the current document library.  It's creating a new item of a custom content type.  I have a associated document templates along the way to the content type and the content list type (for that content type).  What's happening is its now using an old copy of the template, and I can't seem to get it to use anything else.  I've tried recreating the content type, the list, the workflow, the template (inspecting and cleaning) - all no use.  I cannot figure out where this template is coming from.  Thoughts?